# C++: Class within another class as type?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, private

could someone explain me this kind of "inheritance" which can be found in class Y: private?

```
class X
{
  private: char c_;
  public: X(char c) : c_(c){}
};

class Y
{
  private: X x_; // What is this ?
  public: Y(X x): x_(x){}
};

int main()
{
  X m('a');
  Y *test = new Y(m);

  delete test;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the same as `private: char c_;`.  It's just a member variable.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @NathanOliver so it is just synonym ? Has nothing to do with properties from class X ?

Comment: No it is not a synonym.  It declares a class member named `x` that has the type of `X`.  Just like `private: char c_;` declared a class member named `c` of type `char`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 1):

This is not **inheritance**, as `Y` does not derive from `X`.

This is just simple **encapsulation**.  `X x` is just a member variable of `Y`, no different than `char c_` being a member variable of `X`.

Comment: So, it has nothing to do with the `class X` above ?
Member variable of type `X` is saved as number(`int,double`) or as a `char` ?

Comment: @RyadKovach I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @RemyLebau Just wanna make sure, that `class Y` has nothing to do with `class X` ?

Comment: @RyadKovach: `class X` is independent of `class Y`.  `class Y` has a member that is of type `X`, so it depends on `class X`, but is not derived from it.